# Clojure pattern matching on argument's class

Tags: scala, clojure, pattern-matching

I have a simple program written in Scala, which operates logical expressions as members of the case classes, which extend Expr trait (code below). Then I have some functions that simply pattern match on the class of the argument and perform some actions.

```
sealed trait Expr 

case class Implication(lhs: Expr, rhs: Expr) extends Expr {
  override def toString = "(" + lhs.toString + "->" + rhs.toString + ")"
}

case class Negation(body: Expr) extends Expr {
  override def toString = "!" + body.toString
}

case class Conj(lhs: Expr, rhs: Expr) extends Expr {
  override def toString = "(" + lhs.toString + "&" + rhs.toString + ")"
}

case class Disj(lhs: Expr, rhs: Expr) extends Expr {
  override def toString = "(" + lhs.toString + "|" + rhs.toString + ")"
}

case class Variable(name: String) extends Expr {
  override def toString = name
}
```

Example of a function:

```
def substitute(map: m.HashMap[String, Expr]): Expr = this match {
    case Variable(name) => map.getOrElse(name, this)
    case Conj(a, b) => Conj(a.substitute(map), b.substitute(map))
    case Disj(a, b) => Disj(a.substitute(map), b.substitute(map))
    case Implication(a, b) => Implication(a.substitute(map), b.substitute(map))
    case Negation(a) => Negation(a.substitute(map))
}
```

The question is: How can I imitate the same functionality in Clojure? Basically all I want is to distinguish the class of a function argument and pattern match on it, preferably with guards.

Comment: one thing you have to remember is that languages aren't always mappable 1:1, things done in scala may not be possible to do in clojure due to the way clojure handles things... In clojure for example, the function is the smallest piece of code, not the object, you'll rarely ever need to create classes, where in scala, classes rule everything

Comment: I do understand this, but then again I would like to know the Clojure way of handling this situation. I can easily do this in Haskell with it's ADTs and pattern matching, but my knowledge of Clojure is too limited as for now.

Comment: well, case classes are nothing but scala's way of implementing algebraic data-types, the clojure way of doing this is using maps or vectors

Comment: start with a problem description. If you want to test for type/class use `(type x)`

Comment: What is the significance of the `m.` in the argument list `(map: m.HashMap[String, Expr])`?

Comment: I have import scala.collection.{mutable => m} line, so m is an import alias for mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved using `if`, `cond`, `condp` or other conditional operators. To find class use `class` or `type` functions.

Use zippers to walk and edit map tree.
http://ravi.pckl.me/short/functional-xml-editing-using-zippers-in-clojure/

There are many ways to tag entries in map:

- {:tag :Variable :value 42}
- (defrecord Variable [value])

Take a look at enlive for inspiration - https://github.com/cgrand/enlive

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the core of an expression is that it is a recursive data structure with tagged nodes. You could build the expression data structure from an example of a [Red-Black tree](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/02_composite-data/2-27_and_2-28_custom-data-structures/2-27_red-black-trees-part-i.asciidoc) in Clojure.

The key insight is that the expression tree is represented with nested plain Clojure datatypes. In the red-black example, each node is a 4-tuple [type left-child value right-child]. In your example, it might make more sense to represent an expression as [type & children].

In either case, [core.match](https://github.com/clojure/core.match) uses pattern matching against plain Clojure types like vectors and keywords. You could probably port your expression match 1-to-1.